# What can we say if the gradient at the boundary has constant norm?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, boundary-value-problem, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and consider $\Omega$ a smooth and bounded domain in $M$. Let $u : \overline{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function that satisfies both $u = 0$ and $\Vert \nabla u \Vert = 1$ along $\partial \Omega$. **Is it correct to say that**, under these assumptions, $\nabla u$ is the unit normal to $\partial \Omega$ in $M$? In other words, is $\nabla u(x)$ orthogonal to $T_x (\partial \Omega)$ for every $x \in \partial \Omega$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $x \in \partial \Omega$. Let $f (t) = u(\gamma(t))$, where $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \partial \Omega$ is a curve in $\partial \Omega$ such that $\gamma(0) = x$. Since $f \equiv 0$,
$$
0 = f'(0) = \nabla u(\gamma(0)) \cdot \gamma ' (0) = \nabla u(x) \cdot \gamma ' (0)
$$
We conclude that $\nabla u (x)$ is orthogonal to $\gamma ' (0)$.

Every tangent vector is given by $\gamma ' (0)$ for some curve $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \to \partial \Omega$ (this is essentially by definition, though there are many ways to define tangent vectors), so $\nabla u(x)$ must be orthogonal to $T_x (\partial \Omega)$. Since $||\nabla u|| \equiv 1$, $\nabla u$ must be *a* unit normal to $\partial \Omega$. It may not, however, be *the* unit normal to $\partial \Omega$. For example, a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has infinitely many unit normals at every point.

Comment: Musn’t you use, in your proof, the gradient of $u$ restricted to the boundary of $\Omega$?

Comment: What do you mean by the "gradient of $u$ restricted to the boundary of $\Omega$?" If you mean the projection of  $\nabla u$ to $T(\partial \Omega)$, that will be $0$, as the proof shows.